# how to get visual studio C++ toolset tag

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

`Boost` uses `visual studio` tool-set tag in its naming convention of its libraries as mentioned [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming). In visual studio, is there a variable that gives its tool-set tag? It will be helpful to construct library name independent of the tool-set.

> libboost_regex-**vc71**-mt-d-1_34.lib

Above is the tool-set highlighted in the example library name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(PlatformToolsetVersion)` which gives a version number

```
$(ProjectName)-vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion)
```